# Java Code for Ping plotter

Tags: java, networking, monitoring, device

Now I am planning to do the SLA monitoring GUI tool for network devices , As I worked long back in java , I Need your suggestions to do the programming for my project. the requirements are mentioned below .

1. The code continuosly pings the network devices on their IP's to check the reachability
2. It calculates the RTT for the specific target.
3. It returns the report in the graph format to check the status in real time.
4. We need to fetch the device report based on the time.

Comment: Are you asking what language/framework to build GUI with ?